# Powershell FileSystemWatcher stops notifications after some time

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a simple powerscript which watch for a folder for new file addition. The script is watching a root folder. This root folder has multiple sub folders. User can copy a file to any of these sub folders and script will send notification to the user saying a file has been arrived.

The question here is - when the script is started from command line argument, it works for some time. It sends notifications when there is a new file copied to any folder within the root folder. But email notifications are not consistent. It automatically stops sending notifications after couple of minutes even if there is a new file dropped at the folder.

I am using version 5 of Powershell.exe

There is no error in the script. Script still shows status as running but notifications stops.

FileSytemWatcher is working for me but it's not reliable. Experts any suggestions please.

**PS: There is no error printed from Catch block**

```
$FileSystemWatcher = new-object system.io.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.path="\\networklocation\folder"
$FileSystemWatcher.Includesubdirectoriesncludesubdirectories=$true
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEventsnableraisingevents=$true

$action={
   try
    {
        $detail=$event.SourceEventArgs
        $FullPath=$details.FullPath
        $ChangeType=$details.ChangeType
        $FileName=$event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $EmailBody="Something has arrived"
        
        switch($ChangeType)
        {
            'Created' { "CREATED"
                        SendEmail $fromEmailID $usereEmailID $cc $Subject $EMailBody
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                      }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Logwrite($_)
        Write-Host "An error has occured"
        Write-Host $_
    }
    }
    
$handlers = .{
                Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
                }

try
{
    do
        {
            Wait-Event -Timeout 1
        }while ($true)
            
}       
catch
    {
        Logwrite($_)
    }
finally
    {
        LogWrite('Finally')
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
        $handers |
        Remove-Job
        $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents=$false
        $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    }
```

Comment: That being said, I had the exact same problem happens to me 2 years ago. The root cause, in my case, was because the event scriptblock being called when a file changed was returning at some point (not all the time) an error. I suspect you might have the same issue. If for some reason there's an error with your event, it will kill the event registration and all events will stop. Try putting everything from your event scriptblock in a Try/Catch block. That way, even it should continue to run regardless of if something happen.

Comment: "There is no error in the script." I had to correct the following three typos to get it running **without** errors: The property in line 3 has to be `Includesubdirectories`, the property in line 4 has to be `EnableRaisingEvents` and the variable in line 9 has to be called `$details` instead of `$detail`. With those corrections, your script runs and I cannot reproduce your erroneous behaviour. Can you reproduce your error while watching a local path? If not, your problem might be related to your network connection.

Comment: Thank you Sage Pourpare for your advice let me try out that

Are there any limitations on
1. Length of the network path being monitored?
2. If the root folder being monitored has multiple folders in it?
3. If there any many files already present and if any new file is dropped, FileSystemWatcher is failing to monitor new file coming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so much like a couple of the comments stated, there were a few typos in your code... Those were making this impossible to run. I've also cleaned up the syntax a bit. I'm not sure if those were just issues you encountered when pasting your code here or what... I've included the cleaned up code below (**NOTE:** *I did change the order of the parameters passed to SendEmail due to my own iteration of the function*)

Either way, after writing a couple of custom functions to replace LogWrite and SendEmail, the code seems to work fine. A few questions and suggestions to get to the root of your problem:

1. What OS are you running on? There are certain limitations that are imposed by different iterations of Windows.
2. How are you running this? (I.E. Scheduled Task, From the PowerShell terminal, ISE, etc...)
3. Is there any type of network limitation in place which is seeing your outgoing mail as some sort of threat and blocking it? Perhaps have the **SendMail** function log to a file as well.
4. There are some limitations to the FSW from what I understand, including the **InternalBufferSize** which can overflow, causing issues. According to Microsoft (*See references below*) "*The maximum size you can set for the InternalBufferSize property for monitoring a directory over the network is 64 KB.*" Perhaps *resetting* the watchers every **X** number of events using a built in iterator would be a fair compromise to curb this issue.

## Code

```
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path = "\\networklocation\folder"
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubDirectories = $true
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
    try {
        $detail = $event.SourceEventArgs
        $FullPath = $detail.FullPath
        $ChangeType = $detail.ChangeType
        $FileName = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $EmailBody = "$FileName has arrived"
        $Subject = 'A File Has Arrived!'
        
        $Message = "$FileName has arrived"
        LogWrite($Message)
        
        switch ($ChangeType) {
            'Created' {
                "CREATED"
                SendEmail $userEmailID $Subject $EMailBody $fromEmailID #$cc
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Logwrite($_)
        Write-Host "An error has occured"
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
    
$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
}

try {
    do {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    }while ($true)
} catch {
    Logwrite($_)
} finally {
    LogWrite('Enter Finally')
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
    $handers | Remove-Job
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
}
```

#### *Edit:* RE: user1386121 7/10/20

The following code is an example of resetting the File System Watcher every X number of events using a built in iterator.

```
function Initialize-FileSystemWatcher {
    $FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $FileSystemWatcher.Path = "\\networklocation\folder"
    $FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubDirectories = $true
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

    $action = {
        try {
            $detail = $event.SourceEventArgs
            $FullPath = $detail.FullPath
            $ChangeType = $detail.ChangeType
            $FileName = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
            $EmailBody = "$FileName has arrived"
            $Subject = 'A File Has Arrived!'
        
            $Message = "$FileName has arrived"
            LogWrite($Message)
        
            switch ($ChangeType) {
                'Created' {
                    "CREATED"
                    SendEmail $userEmailID $Subject $EMailBody $fromEmailID #$cc
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Logwrite($_)
            Write-Host "An error has occured"
            Write-Host $_
        }
    }
    
    $handlers = . {
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
    }
    @{
        Watcher = $FileSystemWatcher
        Handler = $handlers
    }
}

try {
    LogWrite('Enter Try...')
    $MaxEvents = 5
    while ($true) {
        Write-Host 'New Watcher!'
        $IFSW = Initialize-FileSystemWatcher
        while ($IFSW.Handler.Output.Count -le $MaxEvents) {
            Wait-Event -Timeout 1
        }
        LogWrite('Cleaning Up FileSystemWatcher')
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
        $IFSW.Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
        $IFSW.Watcher.Dispose()
        $IFSW.Handler.Dispose()
        $IFSW = $null
    }
} catch {
    Logwrite($_)
}
```

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize?view=netcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: +1 But there is no need for a `finally` block as the `try` block runs forever. Therefor, also a bad design, because the unregistering never happens, when the execution is aborted with Ctrl+C.

Comment: @Thomas actually in my testing, cancelling with ctrl+c did unregister the FSW every time. I wouldn’t have designed this with a loop either. I believe using the BeginInit and EndInit methods on the FSW object would be proper but I didn’t get that deep into it. That said, if you want to get down to brass tax, registering a file system watcher with PowerShell that’s meant to run indefinitely is ill advised at best because it is a much more resource heavy implementation compared to a compiled executable.

Comment: @rbleattler Thank you for all your efforts to make me understand couple of things. Before I accept it as an answer could you please give some example on "resetting watchers every X number of events using a built in iterator"

Comment: @user1386121 I've updated the answer with an example of just that. best of luck, and thanks for accepting the answer here!

Comment: Thank you rbleattler, this is really helpful. Just couple of question: 
Q1: Is there any way to identify how much the buffer size remaining? Per my understanding the buffer size will go down after each event trigger and will reach to zero?
Q2: It is showing current size as 8192. I tried to read the buffersize in variable but it is not decreasing?
I apologize for any incorrect statements

Comment: @user1386121 from what I understand there is not a way to see the current buffer size, but if you want to try to utilize the buffer for resets, you might get some ideas from the explanation I found here [link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/filesystemwatcher_3.aspx#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20internal%20buffer,and%20notifications%20can%20be%20lost.)

Comment: Yes this link you provided is really helpful. Final question, the reset can also be done in the error event which is mentioned in the email instead of MaxEvent logic? Is my understanding correct? 

_watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(LogBufferError);

void LogBufferError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    ///Reset the FileSystemWatcher here
}

Comment: It’s my understanding that you’d need to add a handler for the error event, and have your inner while loop run until an error even was raised. But I have not tested that. Nor do I know if the errored event would actually fulfill it’s (send mail) action.

Comment: Ok I got it. Anyways you have helped me out by providing enough details for me to do more R n D. Really appreciate your help. Accepting your answer.